# A triangular number is a number that is the sum of the integers from 1 to some integer n

Tags: python

The full question is 
A triangular number is a number that is the sum of the integers from 1 to some integer n. Thus 1 is a triangular number because it's the sum of the integers from 1 to 1; 6 is a triangular number because it's 1+2+3=6.
Given the non-negative integer n, create a list of the first n triangular numbers. Thus is n was 5, the list would be: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]. Associate the list with the variable triangulars.

I have to put it in myprogramminglab.

I have tried the following:

```
sum=0

triangulars = []

for i in range(1,n+1):

    sum += i

triangulars.append(sum)
```

I am getting an error that triangulars does not contain the correct vale.

when I put a value in , it says to delete it.

please help!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the *exact* error text you're seeing? This helps us more precisely identify the problem you're having.

Comment: In this example `n` is not defined, so that could be the issue, but we don't know for sure. If I add `n=6` then there's no error for me.

Comment: If the indentation in your question is accurate, you are only appending to your list once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append should be indented within loop and n should be defined

```
n=int(input('Enter no.of Triangulars you want:'))

triangulars = []

sum=0

for i in range(1,n+1):

        sum += i

        triangulars.append(sum)
```